# Exim4 should not send email to self domain

Tags: exim

My domain, say, example.com, is registered at GoDaddy along with its MX record.
The hosting for example.com is on VPS managed by another hoster.
example.com runs a web server which has a contact form. I want this contact form send emails to info@example.com to the GoDaddy mailbox for which I need to setup exim on VPS to operate as MTA.

I setup exim4 using 'dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config', chose "internet site" option and accept defaults for the rest. However I see that exim tries to deliver emails to info@example com to itself i.o. to GoDaddy.

What I find confusing during 'dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config'

```
Please enter a semicolon-separated list of recipient domains for which
this machine  should consider itself the final destination. These
domains are commonly called  'local domains'. The local hostname and
'localhost' are always added to the list  given here
```

And trying to find a way to NOT include local hostname to this list:

```
man update-exim4.conf
   dc_other_hostnames
          is  used to build the local_domains list, together with "localhost".  This is the list of domains
          for which this machine should consider itself the final destination. The local_domains list  ends
          up in the macro MAIN_LOCAL_DOMAINS.
```

I end up with MAIN_LOCAL_DOMAINS macro but I don't know how can I alter it.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Do you want to receive any mail on this host at all? If not, run `dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config` again and choose "satellite" config (mail sent by smarthost; no local mail). If it only sends to whatever@example.com, you can use the MX host for example.com as the smarthost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit `/etc/exim4/conf.d/main/01_exim4-config_listmacrosdefs` and remove the `MAIN_LOCAL_DOMAINS` word, leaving only `domainlist local_domains =` on that line.

(If you did not choose a split config, edit `/etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template`.)

Execute `service exim4 reload` to regenerate and reload the config.